# Какие нужны знания для перехвата данных ?

Tags: http, https, linux

У меня начальные знания в программировании (Pascal, C, html, немного php, учу ruby). Что нужно для того чтобы написать свой сниффер, как например тот же - DroidSheep ? Чтобы перехватывать данные по Wi-Fi, и прочее.
Заранее спасибо за адекватные ответы.

Comment: Ну, для написания перехватчика C/Pascal/php/Ruby не нужны. Только Java, ну или C++.

Comment: а при чем тут android?

Comment: @SuperCreeper, а как же [whireshark](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=tree)?

[Статистика по языкам](http://www.ohloh.net/p/wireshark/analyses/latest/languages_summary) проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте исходники [DroidSheep](https://code.google.com/p/droidsheep/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2F%20droidsheep%2FDroidSheep_public). Они открыты. Почитайте их, заодно и поймете примерно ваш уровень и куда надо стремиться.